# Reading PPM Image in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, ppm

What is the best way to read a PPM (P6) image file in C# and save it as a Bitmap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the source code provided here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/PixelMapAndImageViewer.aspx

It looks like the PixelMap class (PPM is a "Portable Pixel Map") to open a PPM and save as a Bitmap.